# How to change the color of vim clang complete menu?

Tags: linux, vim, colors, autocomplete, clang

[image]

such as:
how to change the color of clang complete menu to green ?                        Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command:

```
hi! Pmenu ctermfg=x ctermbg=y guibg=z
```

in above command:

```
x: menu foreground color in terminal (0-255)
y: menu background color in terminal (0-255)
z: background color in gvim (hex)
```

Comment: OK. It is good . Thanks a lot. Now the  Popup  menu has different kinds of color